# JSF Primefaces - Things to consider while reverse engineering from database to minimize custom changes

Tags: mysql, jsf-2, primefaces

I have decided to reverse engineer all my JSF (Primefaces) pages from database schema so I can have maximum Create,Read,Edit,List pages ready as per my table structure.

My questions is - What all changes (eg. datatype, size, not null etc) should be done to database tables so that I reverse engineering process handles all validations?

I know/have tried below:
1. Database - NOT NULL => Required value in JSF Page
2. Varchar(30) => Max length is 30 in JSF page
3. email column in database => Email annotation is created in POJO

What are more things which can be handled at database level so that JSF pages generated exactly(or close to exact) as required?
What can be done for password field to be generate in JSF page in reverse engineering process?
Can we add any custom JS function to page in the process to reverse engineering?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listing a exhautive list can be a intensive effort, but I do agree there are some best practice to 'smart' reverse-engineer a model into a web (jsf-primefaces) app.
You need to be able to enrich your model with the following feature to reduce extensive custom alteration.
Having written code generator starting from DB or wsdl for 20+ technologies (http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com) here are my recommandations:

1. **Aliasing**: your DB convention may not match your presentation convention (Ex: table FIN_CREDIT can appear as Credit, field EXCHANGE_RATE_ID should be better displayed as Exchange Rate ...)
2. **Packaging**: tables/views can be packaged regarding their business/technical orientations. It will allow to create menu with submenu
3. **Content-type enrichment**: indicating if a table/view holds masterdata (small amount of data), live-business-data (potentially huge number). It has an effect on how you display the cardinalities. For OneToMany with a DropDown list when is parent entity is a masterdata, otherwise an affectation subUsecase; for many2many: a picklist when the otherside is masterdata, otherwise an affectation subUseCase see (http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/primefaces-Spring)
4. **Stereotype**: the field has a implicit validator assigned to it + a specific presentation  (ex: field ending with _EMAIL have a email validator + a physical display implying email (@))

Minuteproject covers those main aspects whether by individual enrichment (of a specific table, field) or globally using conventions that span over the entire model (example: all tables ending with _TYPE are considered master-data)

A sample reverse-engineered mysql database to primefaces online on cloudbees done by minuteproject that can be found at [petshopapp.minuteproject.cloudbees.net](http://petshopapp.minuteproject.cloudbees.net)

Eventually your last concern was about adding any custom code to the reverse-engineering process:
The classical answer that you will hear is no, with the classical excuse: how can you do not know that Reverse-engineer is a process that erase your customisation!

**But this statement is not true for Minuteproject**. Minuteproject use updatable code, meaning that you can extend or modified portion of your code (java, xhtml, whatever the template within extension or modification areas) and at the next generation your modification will be kept! See http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/Updatable_Generated_Code